# Распределение json данных по дням

Tags: php, json

Ребят подскажите пожалуйста как мне через json decode в php распределить данные по дням. Сейчас у меня выводится все одним списком. Вот сам код json

```html
{
"cod": "200",
"message": 0,
"cnt": 40,
"list": [
{
"dt": 1588172400,
"main": {
"temp": 4.38,
"feels_like": 0.45,
"temp_min": 4.38,
"temp_max": 5.34,
"pressure": 1003,
"sea_level": 1004,
"grnd_level": 989,
"humidity": 83,
"temp_kf": -0.96
},
"weather": [
{
"id": 500,
"main": "Rain",
"description": "небольшой дождь",
"icon": "10d"
}
],
"clouds": {
"all": 94
},
"wind": {
"speed": 3.17,
"deg": 275
},
"rain": {
"3h": 0.47
},
"sys": {
"pod": "d"
},
"dt_txt": "2020-04-29 15:00:00"
},
{
"dt": 1588183200,
"main": {
"temp": 2.89,
"feels_like": -0.73,
"temp_min": 2.73,
"temp_max": 2.89,
"pressure": 1005,
"sea_level": 1006,
"grnd_level": 990,
"humidity": 83,
"temp_kf": 0.16
},
"weather": [
{
"id": 803,
"main": "Clouds",
"description": "облачно с прояснениями",
"icon": "04n"
}
],
"clouds": {
"all": 75
},
"wind": {
"speed": 2.39,
"deg": 223
},
"sys": {
"pod": "n"
},
"dt_txt": "2020-04-29 18:00:00"
},
{
"dt": 1588194000,
"main": {
"temp": 3.16,
"feels_like": -1.14,
"temp_min": 3.14,
"temp_max": 3.16,
"pressure": 1003,
"sea_level": 1003,
"grnd_level": 988,
"humidity": 80,
"temp_kf": 0.02
},
"weather": [
{
"id": 804,
"main": "Clouds",
"description": "пасмурно",
"icon": "04n"
}
],
"clouds": {
"all": 99
},
"wind": {
"speed": 3.32,
"deg": 166
},
"sys": {
"pod": "n"
},
"dt_txt": "2020-04-29 21:00:00"
},
{
"dt": 1588204800,
"main": {
"temp": 5.37,
"feels_like": 0.08,
"temp_min": 5.37,
"temp_max": 5.39,
"pressure": 1001,
"sea_level": 1001,
"grnd_level": 986,
"humidity": 89,
"temp_kf": -0.02
},
"weather": [
{
"id": 501,
"main": "Rain",
"description": "дождь",
"icon": "10n"
}
],
"clouds": {
"all": 99
},
"wind": {
"speed": 5.59,
"deg": 169
},
"rain": {
"3h": 3.56
},
"sys": {
"pod": "n"
},
"dt_txt": "2020-04-30 00:00:00"
},
{
"dt": 1588215600,
"main": {
"temp": 7.53,
"feels_like": 2.34,
"temp_min": 7.53,
"temp_max": 7.53,
"pressure": 999,
"sea_level": 999,
"grnd_level": 984,
"humidity": 86,
"temp_kf": 0
},
"weather": [
{
"id": 500,
"main": "Rain",
"description": "небольшой дождь",
"icon": "10d"
}
],
"clouds": {
"all": 100
},
"wind": {
"speed": 5.91,
"deg": 250
},
"rain": {
"3h": 2.93
},
"sys": {
"pod": "d"
},
"dt_txt": "2020-04-30 03:00:00"
},
{
"dt": 1588226400,
"main": {
"temp": 10.25,
"feels_like": 3.95,
"temp_min": 10.25,
"temp_max": 10.25,
"pressure": 1001,
"sea_level": 1001,
"grnd_level": 986,
"humidity": 64,
"temp_kf": 0
},
"weather": [
{
"id": 500,
"main": "Rain",
"description": "небольшой дождь",
"icon": "10d"
}
],
"clouds": {
"all": 63
},
"wind": {
"speed": 7.05,
"deg": 249
},
"rain": {
"3h": 0.14
},
"sys": {
"pod": "d"
},
"dt_txt": "2020-04-30 06:00:00"
},
{
"dt": 1588237200,
"main": {
"temp": 10.42,
"feels_like": 4.11,
"temp_min": 10.42,
"temp_max": 10.42,
"pressure": 1002,
"sea_level": 1002,
"grnd_level": 987,
"humidity": 58,
"temp_kf": 0
},
"weather": [
{
"id": 500,
"main": "Rain",
"description": "небольшой дождь",
"icon": "10d"
}
],
"clouds": {
"all": 89
},
"wind": {
"speed": 6.75,
"deg": 241
},
"rain": {
"3h": 0.19
},
"sys": {
"pod": "d"
},
"dt_txt": "2020-04-30 09:00:00"
},
{
"dt": 1588248000,
"main": {
"temp": 10.67,
"feels_like": 4.9,
"temp_min": 10.67,
"temp_max": 10.67,
"pressure": 1003,
"sea_level": 1003,
"grnd_level": 988,
"humidity": 57,
"temp_kf": 0
},
"weather": [
{
"id": 500,
"main": "Rain",
"description": "небольшой дождь",
"icon": "10d"
}
],
"clouds": {
"all": 89
},
"wind": {
"speed": 5.97,
"deg": 241
},
"rain": {
"3h": 0.13
},
"sys": {
"pod": "d"
},
"dt_txt": "2020-04-30 12:00:00"
},
{
"dt": 1588258800,
"main": {
"temp": 6.29,
"feels_like": -0.48,
"temp_min": 6.29,
"temp_max": 6.29,
"pressure": 1004,
"sea_level": 1004,
"grnd_level": 989,
"humidity": 65,
"temp_kf": 0
},
"weather": [
{
"id": 500,
"main": "Rain",
"description": "небольшой дождь",
"icon": "10d"
}
],
"clouds": {
"all": 93
},
"wind": {
"speed": 6.87,
"deg": 261
},
"rain": {
"3h": 0.72
},
"sys": {
"pod": "d"
},
"dt_txt": "2020-04-30 15:00:00"
},
{
"dt": 1588269600,
"main": {
"temp": 4.27,
"feels_like": -0.87,
"temp_min": 4.27,
"temp_max": 4.27,
"pressure": 1008,
"sea_level": 1008,
"grnd_level": 992,
"humidity": 80,
"temp_kf": 0
},
"weather": [
{
"id": 803,
"main": "Clouds",
"description": "облачно с прояснениями",
"icon": "04n"
}
],
"clouds": {
"all": 57
},
"wind": {
"speed": 4.75,
"deg": 249
},
"sys": {
"pod": "n"
},
"dt_txt": "2020-04-30 18:00:00"
},
{
"dt": 1588280400,
"main": {
"temp": 4.14,
"feels_like": -1.98,
"temp_min": 4.14,
"temp_max": 4.14,
"pressure": 1009,
"sea_level": 1009,
"grnd_level": 994,
"humidity": 76,
"temp_kf": 0
},
"weather": [
{
"id": 500,
"main": "Rain",
"description": "небольшой дождь",
"icon": "10n"
}
],
"clouds": {
"all": 97
},
"wind": {
"speed": 5.97,
"deg": 274
},
"rain": {
"3h": 0.23
},
"sys": {
"pod": "n"
},
"dt_txt": "2020-04-30 21:00:00"
},
{
"dt": 1588291200,
"main": {
"temp": 3.35,
"feels_like": -2.36,
"temp_min": 3.35,
"temp_max": 3.35,
"pressure": 1012,
"sea_level": 1012,
"grnd_level": 996,
"humidity": 77,
"temp_kf": 0
},
"weather": [
{
"id": 804,
"main": "Clouds",
"description": "пасмурно",
"icon": "04n"
}
],
"clouds": {
"all": 96
},
"wind": {
"speed": 5.26,
"deg": 262
},
"sys": {
"pod": "n"
},
"dt_txt": "2020-05-01 00:00:00"
},
{
"dt": 1588302000,
"main": {
"temp": 3.34,
"feels_like": -2.79,
"temp_min": 3.34,
"temp_max": 3.34,
"pressure": 1013,
"sea_level": 1013,
"grnd_level": 998,
"humidity": 76,
"temp_kf": 0
},
"weather": [
{
"id": 803,
"main": "Clouds",
"description": "облачно с прояснениями",
"icon": "04d"
}
],
"clouds": {
"all": 63
},
"wind": {
"speed": 5.82,
"deg": 264
},
"sys": {
"pod": "d"
},
"dt_txt": "2020-05-01 03:00:00"
},
{
"dt": 1588312800,
"main": {
"temp": 6.09,
"feels_like": 0.24,
"temp_min": 6.09,
"temp_max": 6.09,
"pressure": 1015,
"sea_level": 1015,
"grnd_level": 999,
"humidity": 63,
"temp_kf": 0
},
"weather": [
{
"id": 803,
"main": "Clouds",
"description": "облачно с прояснениями",
"icon": "04d"
}
],
"clouds": {
"all": 66
},
"wind": {
"speed": 5.44,
"deg": 269
},
"sys": {
"pod": "d"
},
"dt_txt": "2020-05-01 06:00:00"
},
{
"dt": 1588323600,
"main": {
"temp": 9.62,
"feels_like": 3.85,
"temp_min": 9.62,
"temp_max": 9.62,
"pressure": 1015,
"sea_level": 1015,
"grnd_level": 1000,
"humidity": 48,
"temp_kf": 0
},
"weather": [
{
"id": 801,
"main": "Clouds",
"description": "небольшая облачность",
"icon": "02d"
}
],
"clouds": {
"all": 22
},
"wind": {
"speed": 5.23,
"deg": 275
},
"sys": {
"pod": "d"
},
"dt_txt": "2020-05-01 09:00:00"
},
{
"dt": 1588334400,
"main": {
"temp": 9.78,
"feels_like": 4.87,
"temp_min": 9.78,
"temp_max": 9.78,
"pressure": 1015,
"sea_level": 1015,
"grnd_level": 1000,
"humidity": 47,
"temp_kf": 0
},
"weather": [
{
"id": 803,
"main": "Clouds",
"description": "облачно с прояснениями",
"icon": "04d"
}
],
"clouds": {
"all": 51
},
"wind": {
"speed": 3.98,
"deg": 278
},
"sys": {
"pod": "d"
},
"dt_txt": "2020-05-01 12:00:00"
},
{
"dt": 1588345200,
"main": {
"temp": 8.02,
"feels_like": 5.37,
"temp_min": 8.02,
"temp_max": 8.02,
"pressure": 1015,
"sea_level": 1015,
"grnd_level": 1000,
"humidity": 62,
"temp_kf": 0
},
"weather": [
{
"id": 804,
"main": "Clouds",
"description": "пасмурно",
"icon": "04d"
}
],
"clouds": {
"all": 100
},
"wind": {
"speed": 1.2,
"deg": 285
},
"sys": {
"pod": "d"
},
"dt_txt": "2020-05-01 15:00:00"
},
{
"dt": 1588356000,
"main": {
"temp": 3.99,
"feels_like": 1.13,
"temp_min": 3.99,
"temp_max": 3.99,
"pressure": 1016,
"sea_level": 1016,
"grnd_level": 1000,
"humidity": 76,
"temp_kf": 0
},
"weather": [
{
"id": 804,
"main": "Clouds",
"description": "пасмурно",
"icon": "04n"
}
],
"clouds": {
"all": 93
},
"wind": {
"speed": 1.28,
"deg": 15
},
"sys": {
"pod": "n"
},
"dt_txt": "2020-05-01 18:00:00"
},
{
"dt": 1588366800,
"main": {
"temp": 2.18,
"feels_like": -0.73,
"temp_min": 2.18,
"temp_max": 2.18,
"pressure": 1015,
"sea_level": 1015,
"grnd_level": 1000,
"humidity": 81,
"temp_kf": 0
},
"weather": [
{
"id": 802,
"main": "Clouds",
"description": "переменная облачность",
"icon": "03n"
}
],
"clouds": {
"all": 27
},
"wind": {
"speed": 1.17,
"deg": 16
},
"sys": {
"pod": "n"
},
"dt_txt": "2020-05-01 21:00:00"
},
{
"dt": 1588377600,
"main": {
"temp": 1.34,
"feels_like": -1.73,
"temp_min": 1.34,
"temp_max": 1.34,
"pressure": 1016,
"sea_level": 1016,
"grnd_level": 1000,
"humidity": 85,
"temp_kf": 0
},
"weather": [
{
"id": 802,
"main": "Clouds",
"description": "переменная облачность",
"icon": "03n"
}
],
"clouds": {
"all": 40
},
"wind": {
"speed": 1.37,
"deg": 326
},
"sys": {
"pod": "n"
},
"dt_txt": "2020-05-02 00:00:00"
},
{
"dt": 1588388400,
"main": {
"temp": 3.45,
"feels_like": -0.47,
"temp_min": 3.45,
"temp_max": 3.45,
"pressure": 1016,
"sea_level": 1016,
"grnd_level": 1001,
"humidity": 77,
"temp_kf": 0
},
"weather": [
{
"id": 803,
"main": "Clouds",
"description": "облачно с прояснениями",
"icon": "04d"
}
],
"clouds": {
"all": 55
},
"wind": {
"speed": 2.73,
"deg": 321
},
"sys": {
"pod": "d"
},
"dt_txt": "2020-05-02 03:00:00"
},
{
"dt": 1588399200,
"main": {
"temp": 6.72,
"feels_like": 1.61,
"temp_min": 6.72,
"temp_max": 6.72,
"pressure": 1017,
"sea_level": 1017,
"grnd_level": 1001,
"humidity": 57,
"temp_kf": 0
},
"weather": [
{
"id": 802,
"main": "Clouds",
"description": "переменная облачность",
"icon": "03d"
}
],
"clouds": {
"all": 48
},
"wind": {
"speed": 4.23,
"deg": 306
},
"sys": {
"pod": "d"
},
"dt_txt": "2020-05-02 06:00:00"
},
{
"dt": 1588410000,
"main": {
"temp": 8.14,
"feels_like": 2.05,
"temp_min": 8.14,
"temp_max": 8.14,
"pressure": 1017,
"sea_level": 1017,
"grnd_level": 1001,
"humidity": 52,
"temp_kf": 0
},
"weather": [
{
"id": 802,
"main": "Clouds",
"description": "переменная облачность",
"icon": "03d"
}
],
"clouds": {
"all": 34
},
"wind": {
"speed": 5.64,
"deg": 302
},
"sys": {
"pod": "d"
},
"dt_txt": "2020-05-02 09:00:00"
},
{
"dt": 1588420800,
"main": {
"temp": 6.96,
"feels_like": 1.07,
"temp_min": 6.96,
"temp_max": 6.96,
"pressure": 1017,
"sea_level": 1017,
"grnd_level": 1002,
"humidity": 56,
"temp_kf": 0
},
"weather": [
{
"id": 802,
"main": "Clouds",
"description": "переменная облачность",
"icon": "03d"
}
],
"clouds": {
"all": 48
},
"wind": {
"speed": 5.34,
"deg": 315
},
"sys": {
"pod": "d"
},
"dt_txt": "2020-05-02 12:00:00"
},
{
"dt": 1588431600,
"main": {
"temp": 5.46,
"feels_like": 0.44,
"temp_min": 5.46,
"temp_max": 5.46,
"pressure": 1018,
"sea_level": 1018,
"grnd_level": 1003,
"humidity": 62,
"temp_kf": 0
},
"weather": [
{
"id": 802,
"main": "Clouds",
"description": "переменная облачность",
"icon": "03d"
}
],
"clouds": {
"all": 28
},
"wind": {
"speed": 4.09,
"deg": 313
},
"sys": {
"pod": "d"
},
"dt_txt": "2020-05-02 15:00:00"
},
{
"dt": 1588442400,
"main": {
"temp": 2.18,
"feels_like": -2.22,
"temp_min": 2.18,
"temp_max": 2.18,
"pressure": 1020,
"sea_level": 1020,
"grnd_level": 1005,
"humidity": 78,
"temp_kf": 0
},
"weather": [
{
"id": 801,
"main": "Clouds",
"description": "небольшая облачность",
"icon": "02n"
}
],
"clouds": {
"all": 14
},
"wind": {
"speed": 3.2,
"deg": 329
},
"sys": {
"pod": "n"
},
"dt_txt": "2020-05-02 18:00:00"
},
{
"dt": 1588453200,
"main": {
"temp": 0.1,
"feels_like": -3.75,
"temp_min": 0.1,
"temp_max": 0.1,
"pressure": 1022,
"sea_level": 1022,
"grnd_level": 1006,
"humidity": 91,
"temp_kf": 0
},
"weather": [
{
"id": 800,
"main": "Clear",
"description": "ясно",
"icon": "01n"
}
],
"clouds": {
"all": 0
},
"wind": {
"speed": 2.42,
"deg": 331
},
"sys": {
"pod": "n"
},
"dt_txt": "2020-05-02 21:00:00"
},
{
"dt": 1588464000,
"main": {
"temp": -0.92,
"feels_like": -4.43,
"temp_min": -0.92,
"temp_max": -0.92,
"pressure": 1023,
"sea_level": 1023,
"grnd_level": 1007,
"humidity": 96,
"temp_kf": 0
},
"weather": [
{
"id": 800,
"main": "Clear",
"description": "ясно",
"icon": "01n"
}
],
"clouds": {
"all": 0
},
"wind": {
"speed": 1.89,
"deg": 324
},
"sys": {
"pod": "n"
},
"dt_txt": "2020-05-03 00:00:00"
},
{
"dt": 1588474800,
"main": {
"temp": 2.26,
"feels_like": -1.93,
"temp_min": 2.26,
"temp_max": 2.26,
"pressure": 1024,
"sea_level": 1024,
"grnd_level": 1009,
"humidity": 77,
"temp_kf": 0
},
"weather": [
{
"id": 800,
"main": "Clear",
"description": "ясно",
"icon": "01d"
}
],
"clouds": {
"all": 0
},
"wind": {
"speed": 2.88,
"deg": 333
},
"sys": {
"pod": "d"
},
"dt_txt": "2020-05-03 03:00:00"
},
{
"dt": 1588485600,
"main": {
"temp": 6.59,
"feels_like": 2.25,
"temp_min": 6.59,
"temp_max": 6.59,
"pressure": 1024,
"sea_level": 1024,
"grnd_level": 1009,
"humidity": 57,
"temp_kf": 0
},
"weather": [
{
"id": 800,
"main": "Clear",
"description": "ясно",
"icon": "01d"
}
],
"clouds": {
"all": 0
},
"wind": {
"speed": 3.1,
"deg": 341
},
"sys": {
"pod": "d"
},
"dt_txt": "2020-05-03 06:00:00"
},
{
"dt": 1588496400,
"main": {
"temp": 9.71,
"feels_like": 5.41,
"temp_min": 9.71,
"temp_max": 9.71,
"pressure": 1024,
"sea_level": 1024,
"grnd_level": 1009,
"humidity": 46,
"temp_kf": 0
},
"weather": [
{
"id": 800,
"main": "Clear",
"description": "ясно",
"icon": "01d"
}
],
"clouds": {
"all": 1
},
"wind": {
"speed": 3.03,
"deg": 336
},
"sys": {
"pod": "d"
},
"dt_txt": "2020-05-03 09:00:00"
},
{
"dt": 1588507200,
"main": {
"temp": 10.82,
"feels_like": 6.75,
"temp_min": 10.82,
"temp_max": 10.82,
"pressure": 1024,
"sea_level": 1024,
"grnd_level": 1009,
"humidity": 43,
"temp_kf": 0
},
"weather": [
{
"id": 800,
"main": "Clear",
"description": "ясно",
"icon": "01d"
}
],
"clouds": {
"all": 0
},
"wind": {
"speed": 2.72,
"deg": 323
},
"sys": {
"pod": "d"
},
"dt_txt": "2020-05-03 12:00:00"
},
{
"dt": 1588518000,
"main": {
"temp": 8.27,
"feels_like": 5.07,
"temp_min": 8.27,
"temp_max": 8.27,
"pressure": 1024,
"sea_level": 1024,
"grnd_level": 1009,
"humidity": 52,
"temp_kf": 0
},
"weather": [
{
"id": 800,
"main": "Clear",
"description": "ясно",
"icon": "01d"
}
],
"clouds": {
"all": 0
},
"wind": {
"speed": 1.53,
"deg": 335
},
"sys": {
"pod": "d"
},
"dt_txt": "2020-05-03 15:00:00"
},
{
"dt": 1588528800,
"main": {
"temp": 4.15,
"feels_like": 1.49,
"temp_min": 4.15,
"temp_max": 4.15,
"pressure": 1026,
"sea_level": 1026,
"grnd_level": 1010,
"humidity": 67,
"temp_kf": 0
},
"weather": [
{
"id": 800,
"main": "Clear",
"description": "ясно",
"icon": "01n"
}
],
"clouds": {
"all": 7
},
"wind": {
"speed": 0.68,
"deg": 73
},
"sys": {
"pod": "n"
},
"dt_txt": "2020-05-03 18:00:00"
},
{
"dt": 1588539600,
"main": {
"temp": 2.84,
"feels_like": -0.23,
"temp_min": 2.84,
"temp_max": 2.84,
"pressure": 1026,
"sea_level": 1026,
"grnd_level": 1010,
"humidity": 74,
"temp_kf": 0
},
"weather": [
{
"id": 800,
"main": "Clear",
"description": "ясно",
"icon": "01n"
}
],
"clouds": {
"all": 9
},
"wind": {
"speed": 1.28,
"deg": 98
},
"sys": {
"pod": "n"
},
"dt_txt": "2020-05-03 21:00:00"
},
{
"dt": 1588550400,
"main": {
"temp": 1.86,
"feels_like": -1.09,
"temp_min": 1.86,
"temp_max": 1.86,
"pressure": 1027,
"sea_level": 1027,
"grnd_level": 1011,
"humidity": 80,
"temp_kf": 0
},
"weather": [
{
"id": 803,
"main": "Clouds",
"description": "облачно с прояснениями",
"icon": "04n"
}
],
"clouds": {
"all": 52
},
"wind": {
"speed": 1.13,
"deg": 116
},
"sys": {
"pod": "n"
},
"dt_txt": "2020-05-04 00:00:00"
},
{
"dt": 1588561200,
"main": {
"temp": 5.72,
"feels_like": 2.5,
"temp_min": 5.72,
"temp_max": 5.72,
"pressure": 1028,
"sea_level": 1028,
"grnd_level": 1012,
"humidity": 63,
"temp_kf": 0
},
"weather": [
{
"id": 802,
"main": "Clouds",
"description": "переменная облачность",
"icon": "03d"
}
],
"clouds": {
"all": 45
},
"wind": {
"speed": 1.61,
"deg": 138
},
"sys": {
"pod": "d"
},
"dt_txt": "2020-05-04 03:00:00"
},
{
"dt": 1588572000,
"main": {
"temp": 10.15,
"feels_like": 6.68,
"temp_min": 10.15,
"temp_max": 10.15,
"pressure": 1027,
"sea_level": 1027,
"grnd_level": 1012,
"humidity": 48,
"temp_kf": 0
},
"weather": [
{
"id": 803,
"main": "Clouds",
"description": "облачно с прояснениями",
"icon": "04d"
}
],
"clouds": {
"all": 70
},
"wind": {
"speed": 2.05,
"deg": 159
},
"sys": {
"pod": "d"
},
"dt_txt": "2020-05-04 06:00:00"
},
{
"dt": 1588582800,
"main": {
"temp": 12.5,
"feels_like": 9.07,
"temp_min": 12.5,
"temp_max": 12.5,
"pressure": 1027,
"sea_level": 1027,
"grnd_level": 1012,
"humidity": 40,
"temp_kf": 0
},
"weather": [
{
"id": 804,
"main": "Clouds",
"description": "пасмурно",
"icon": "04d"
}
],
"clouds": {
"all": 100
},
"wind": {
"speed": 1.92,
"deg": 180
},
"sys": {
"pod": "d"
},
"dt_txt": "2020-05-04 09:00:00"
},
{
"dt": 1588593600,
"main": {
"temp": 14.26,
"feels_like": 11.27,
"temp_min": 14.26,
"temp_max": 14.26,
"pressure": 1026,
"sea_level": 1026,
"grnd_level": 1011,
"humidity": 38,
"temp_kf": 0
},
"weather": [
{
"id": 803,
"main": "Clouds",
"description": "облачно с прояснениями",
"icon": "04d"
}
],
"clouds": {
"all": 78
},
"wind": {
"speed": 1.46,
"deg": 176
},
"sys": {
"pod": "d"
},
"dt_txt": "2020-05-04 12:00:00"
}
],
"city": {
"id": 579132,
"name": "Барда",
"coord": {
"lat": 56.9277,
"lon": 55.5934
},
"country": "RU",
"timezone": 18000,
"sunrise": 1588120434,
"sunset": 1588175746
}
}
```

Comment: После декода отсортировать.

Comment: Это я знаю, вот как раз помощи и прошу в сартировке

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете это сделать с помощью цикла foreach

```
    // декодируем полученные данные
    $dataJson = json_decode($data);
    $arrayDays = $dataJson->list;

    // выводим данные
    foreach($arrayDays as $oneDay){
        //Здесь выводим нужную информация из $oneDay, например так:
       echo "<div>Температура: " . round($oneDay->main->temp) . " &#176;C</div>";
       echo "<div>Ощущается как: " . round($oneDay->main->feels_like) . " &#176;C</div>";
       echo "<div>Скорость ветра: " . round($oneDay->wind->speed) . " м/c</div>";
       echo "<div>Направление ветра: " . $oneDay->wind->deg . "</div>";
       echo "<div>Влажность: " . $oneDay->main->humidity . " %</div>";
    }

    ?>
```

Comment: @pheronex так же выводит одним списком, не распределяет по дням. Допустим:Понедельник - данные, Вторник - данные. и т.д.

Comment: То что выше код написали это у меня все сделано, у меня по дням сортировать не получается. Именно это в тайтле вопроса написано

Comment: Ну так выведите время аналогично выведенным мной данным, оно присутствует в json в переменной dt_txt.

Comment: вы меня не поняли, время у меня выведено. Мне нужно совсем другое распределение по дням недели. Мне не нужно списком. То что вы пишите я все сделал еще до того как задать вопрос @pheroneex